# How to automatically generate assertion information?

Tags: python, python-3.x, assertion

In python, whenever I use assertion and it is triggered, I only got an ugly information:

```
AssertionError
```

What should I do to automatically generate a message that explained the cause of the error, by parsing the AST of the condition argument?

e.g.: So

```
assert 2 == 3
```

causes:

```
AssertionError: 2 != 3
```

Comment: Just use pytest?

Comment: I want to, but I'm not sure if pytest will ever support jupyter notebook :-<

Comment: If jupyter support is a limitation you should really have it *in the question*.

Answer (score 0):

If dependencies is an issue you can do it easily yourself. ie:

```
def assert_eq(x, y):
  if x != y:
    print('error: {} != {}'.format(x, y))
  assert x == y
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve your goal would be to use a wrapper function that takes the asserted condition as a string parameter, so that you can `eval` it and `assert` the result, while catching the `AssertionError` in a `try` block, so that you can re-raise the exception with the given string as a message:

```
def my_assert(condition):
    try:
        assert eval(condition)
    except AssertionError as e:
        e.args = condition,
        raise
```

so that:

```
my_assert('2 == 3')
```

would raise:

```
AssertionError: 2 == 3
```

Comment: Needs a little more detail to show how it would work with x and y, I think. This function won't know those variables if called with "x == y"`

Comment: It doesn't need to. The condition is passed in as a string and is `eval`'d directly so it's up to the Python compiler to interpret it. What this answer doesn't do is to raise the error with a condition opposite to the given one (so `2 == 3` is reported as `2 != 3`), which is what the OP states he/she wants it to but I don't think is necessary for his/her purpose.

Comment: `eval` has security implications. Consider `ast.literal_eval` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197698/2958070

Comment: @Ben Unless all your assertions are for constants `ast.literal_eval` is not suited for the purpose since chances are variable names are involved in the given condition, which `ast.literal_eval` won't be able to resolve. Assertions are for development anyway and production code should be stripped of assertions, so security should no be a concern in the first place.

Comment: @blhsing I didn't realize about variables screwing with `ast.literal_eval`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since `AssertionError` is a class, you can derive your own that does what you want. The tricky part is hooking it up so the interpreter will use it with `assert` statment.

Here's something that seems to work, but I don't know whether that will be the case when used in conjunction with jupyter notebook.

```
import builtins
import traceback


class MyAssertionError(builtins.AssertionError):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyAssertionError, self).__init__(*args)
        raw_tb = traceback.extract_stack()
        entries = traceback.format_list(raw_tb)

        # Remove the last two entries for the call to extract_stack(). Each
        # entry consists of single string with consisting of two lines, the
        # script file path then the line of source code making the call to this
        # function.
        del entries[-2:]
        self.lines = '\n'.join(entries)

    def __str__(self):
        return super(MyAssertionError, self).__str__() + '\n' + self.lines

builtins.AssertionError = MyAssertionError  # Replace builtin.


if __name__ == '__main__':

    assert 2 == 3
```